# p:dataGrid content disappears after ajax update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid, ajax-update

I got a little problem with p:ajax update here. After closing p:panel or checking checkbox or adding answer i'm ajax-updating ans-data-grid as you can see in the code. But it works only for add answer button. When i close panel or click checkbox content of p:datagrid dissapears. It's still there but it is not visible and whole datagrid is 0px high. So my question is, Is there a difference between update from p:commandButton and p:ajax, and if yes how can i update this datagrid properly?

```
<p:panel id="edit_ans_panel" styleClass="edit-ans-panel"  visible="#{editorBean.question.qtype != 2}">
                        <p:dataGrid rowIndexVar="rowIndex" var="answer" value="#{editorBean.question.answers}" columns="1" id="ans_data_grid">
                            <p:panel  header="Answer" styleClass="QApanel" closable="#{editorBean.closableAns}" toggleable="true">
                                <p:ajax event="close" update="ans_data_grid" listener="#{editorBean.onAnswerRemoved(answer)}" />
                                <p:panelGrid columnClasses="anscol1,anscol2,anscol3" columns="3" layout="grid" styleClass="QAgrid">
                                    <p:inputTextarea placeholder="enclose LaTeX expression in $ to be processed" id="editor_input_#{answer.id_answer}" styleClass="editor-input" minQueryLength="2" value="#{answer.text}" />
                                    <h:outputText id="editor_output_#{answer.id_answer}" styleClass="editor-output" value="#{answer.text}"/>
                                    <p:column>
                                        <p:panel id="edit_ans_corr_chkbx" styleClass="edit-ans-corr-chkbx" visible="#{editorBean.question.qtype != 3}">
                                            <h:outputText value="Correct: " />
                                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="is_true_#{answer.id_answer}" value="#{answer.is_true}" >
                                                <p:ajax update="ans_data_grid" listener="#{editorBean.ansChecked(answer)}" />
                                            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                        </p:panel>
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                            </p:panel>
                        </p:dataGrid>
                        <p:commandButton id="add_ans_btn" value="Add Answer" styleClass="add-ans-btn" action="#{editorBean.addAnswer()}" update="ans_data_grid"/>
                    </p:panel>
```

**\edit**
For some reason p:panel with .QApanel class gets .ui-helper-hidden class after update where is display:none.

Comment: I've had this problem as well. I ended up having to tap dance around the problem, however, a direct solution would be greatly beneficial.

Comment: @NullPtr92065 Yes, i'm thinking about some workaround, but it would be better if someone knows better solution.

Comment: @NullPtr92065 you can see reson of this in the edit, i fixed this with forced display:block !important; but i would like to know the reason of this so im not posting this as answer.

Comment: My best guess is there is a bug with this component. If you really want to dig into this, download the PF source code and look as the JavaScript and corresponding rendering logic.

Comment: @NullPtr92065 That's my guess too, if i get some free time i'll take a look at it